# Navigation Bar isn't not showing up

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

I'm using `MGSplitViewController` for my iPad application.

I have added a `viewController` to it's `detailViewController` this way:

```
my2ndVC *vc = [[my2ndVC alloc] init];
splitViewController.detailViewController = vc;
```

It works perfect, now when I'm adding a navigationBar to `my2ndVC`

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 448, 44)];

[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

**The bar isn't showing up.**

I know I can add `my2ndVC` like this:

```
my2ndVC *vc = [[my2ndVC alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
splitViewController.detailViewController = navController;
```

But then I also have a condition in one of my view controller:

```
if ([splitViewController.detailViewController isKindOfClass:[my2ndVC class]])
```

What would be the suggested workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you change your condition as follows:

```
if ([splitViewController.detailViewController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[my2ndVC class]])
```

To Make it simpler :

```
UINavigationController *aNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)splitViewController.detailViewController;
if ([aNavigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[my2ndVC class]]) {
    // TRUE...
}
```

Comment: What was I thinking when I posted the question. :P I'll try it. Thanks.